# PHP - Recalling information stored in database using sessions

Tags: php, session

I've got problem when using sessions to recall data stored in mySQL database. This is my code:

The login page is simple, the input your username and password kind (i know the password is still plaintext, i plan to change it later).

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db_name="proyek";
$tbl_name="murid";
mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")or die("Cannot connect to SQL."); 
mysql_select_db('$db_name');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            LOGO
            <h1 align="center">TITLE</h1>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="login">
            <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                <table border="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>NIS</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="nislogin" id="nislogin"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="pwdlogin" id="pwdlogin"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbutton" id="loginbutton" value="Login"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the code for login check page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db_name="proyek";
$tbl_name="murid";
mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")or die("Cannot connect to SQL."); 
mysql_select_db('$db_name');

$nis=($_POST['nislogin']);
$pwd=($_POST['pwdlogin']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM murid WHERE nis='$nis' and password='$pwd'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
    $_SESSION['nislogin']=$nis;
    $nama=$result['nama'];
    $_SESSION['nama']=$nama;
    header("location:index.php");
    return true;
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo("Wrong NIS or password.");
    return false;
}
?>
```

i have entered some dummy data in database for testing purposes; id, password, name. how can i recall something from database while user only login with username/id?

i'd like to display something like 'hello, name' in the next page. Help is appreciated.

edit: I've edited my code based on feedbacks and it produces blank; like 'Hello,' with no name.

Comment: If you want to display the name, you'd better add it to the session as well so that you can access it without having to query the database again in the next page.

Comment: like $_SESSION['name']=$result['name']? see above.

Comment: Yes, if `name` is a column in your table of course.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['nama']))` session should start before that line.

Comment: i have 'name' on my table, and it produces error like this: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: Always put `session_start();` at the top of your script / page if it is going to use the session.

Comment: @jeroen in login page or in page that checks login? no point putting in login page where no session starts i suppose.

Comment: Could SQL Inject your site in ~1 minute. Let's hope you aren't storing sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you are running a query on your login check page, use that value for your session rather than the post data. Also, whenever you are redirecting, always exit your script.

**EDIT:**

Since you are in the development stage, you need to display an error if your query fails so you know why. I also realized you need to return an associative array to access the row. Try this.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM murid WHERE nis='$nis' and password='$pwd'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // since you are only accessing one row,  
    // otherwise you would put this in a loop to build your array.

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nislogin']=$data['nis'];
    header("location:index.php");
    return true;
    exit;
}
```

I also see this session on your login page, but I don't see that you ever created it and I don't see the purpose.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['nama']))
{
unset($_SESSION['nama']);
}
```

Basically all you need from here, is to start the session on `index.php` and output it.

**index.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['nislogin']))
{
$name = $_SESSION['nislogin'];
} else {
$name = "stranger";
}

<body>
Welcome, <?=$name?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, do I need to place session_start() straight on index.php or page that checks login? Since in that page session is first created. And i have a table with name column on it, i need to call that instead assigning name variable to a string.

Comment: You need `session_start()` anywhere you need to use the session. So  first on the page it was created, then also on any page where you need to use it (index.php).